# How do I select all parts of a path curve at once?

Tags: bezier-curves, selection-tools

I want to select all the parts of a path curve at once, similar to alt-click for normal meshes. How do I do this?[image]

I want to select all the points at once.

Comment: 'A' in Edit mode will select all control-points. 'Ctrl-L' will select all points connected to an existing selection. 'L' will select all points connected to the point under the mouse. This applies to meshes, as  well.

Comment: ctrl l worked. Though I would prefer a solution that requires less inputs like alt click, I suppose it works well enough.